# Using list created in main method in other classes

Tags: c#, .net-core

I created a list of class type in my main method from a csv data. Now I want to access the list that is created in main method in other classes of my program. How should I do it.

```
class program{
    private <myclass> list = new List<myclass>() ;
    public static void main() 
    {
        // importer is object of csv importer class
        var list= importer.Import<myclass>("csv path")
    }
}

public class myclass{
    private int num;
    private string name;
}

public class class1{
    //Here I want to use the list of 
    // myclass type . 
}
```

I tried creating the list in the program class and creating a function `getlist()` but it still leads to error

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. This is not a guided tutorial site.  You should get a good tutorial or book.

Comment: I edited your question. Please note that `public` should be lower case, not `Public`. There are several ways to do this, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is not about asp.net, but is a general C# question.

There are several ways to share data between classes. You can either expose a `public` field, property, or method and call that from the other class.

Here is an example of access another class using public field:

```
public class program {
    // this should be static because the method that assigns to it is static
    public static List<myclass> list = new List<myclass>();
    public static void main() 
    {
        // assign the list to the public static field.
        list = importer.Import<myclass>("csv path");
    }
}

public class Class1 {
    public void MyMethod() {
        // now you can access the `public static` field heere
        // for example
        Console.WriteLIne(program.list.Count);
    }
}
```

Or you can pass in the data into the constructor of another class.

```
public class program {
    public static void main() 
    {
        // assign the list to the public field
        var list = importer.Import<myclass>("csv path");

        // pass data through constructor, now other class has that data
        var myOtherObject = new MyOtherClass(list);
    }
}

public class MyOtherClass {
    private List<myclass> list;

    // here is the constructor that takes the list
    public MyOtherClass(List<myclass> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void SomeMethod() {
        // now you can use this.list with the data from main here.
    }
}
```

Comment: J was doing the same thing except I didn't make it static. I still didn't get why it has to be static.

Comment: @proto static methods, like `main` in your example, cannot access non-static fields. non-static fields must be accessed via an instance/object.